# How do I load a modal with delay on a particular slider image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am able to make my modal appear on the first slide, the problem is when the second slide comes around, I'd also like to have a delay before the modal appears. How would I do this in javascript so that, at each slider, my modal appears with a delay of 2 seconds, after which when the slider comes back around, it goes back to default and restarts the delay process again?

```
<style>
.myModal {
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%; /* Full width */
   height: 650px; /* Full height */
   overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); /* Black w/ opacity */
   display: none;
   }
</style>




<div class="myModal">
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".myModal").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Is there any time to slide (pass to the next slide) for your slider ? or is it a manual slide ?

Comment: The slider is set to 8 seconds, then it goes to the next slide. I'd like for jQuery to kick in on each slide and have the same delay with the modal appearing for each slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to repeat that everytime a new slide is on  so you can use this :

```
setInterval(yourFunction() }, 8000);
```

`yourFunction()` is the function that make your modal appear under your conditions.

Comment: I tried this, and it works, but when it comes back around to the first slider, then the modal stays. How can I have it repeat the process each time? I tried fadeOut() and that works but is kind of sloppy. I just want the modal to appear at each slider and disappear when it goes to the next.

Comment: you have to close each modal before calling the next one !